# Creating "shortcuts" macro-like definitions

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

In my code I've been rewriting `static_cast<int *>` about a million times, is there a way to redefine a keyword so that whenever I call this it does the same thing?

example

`cast` would do the same thing as `static_cast<int *>`

Comment: When you say rewriting are you sure regex can't help any?

Comment: I recommend not doing this - over time this makes code unreadable - instead I suggest Mavis Beacon and learn to type faster :-) (seriously I type around 100wpm)

Comment: If it's any consolation, you could probably configure the IDE so you can type "sc" or whatever you want, hit a hotkey, and have it expand into `static_cast<|>`.

Comment: There's a reason C++ casts are annoying to write: every time you write one, you should be wondering if you can restructure your code to avoid it.

Comment: @AndréCaron do not forget they are a lot easier to grep for than (char*) as well :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`static_cast` has the benefit that C++ programmers will recognize exactly what it is without needing to go find your `#define` or other statement. I would highly recommend you continue to use `static_cast`.

However, my assumption is that your problem is the number of keystrokes required, and so the best solution would be to use a text editor which supports macros. This way, the code that ends up saved does use the standard `static_cast<T>(x)` syntax, but you may only need to type something such as <kbd>[</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>]</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>T</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd>.

Information on how to do such will be found in documentation of such editors. I'm not a big fan of highly-customizable editors, so specifics are beyond my knowledge.

Comment: Thanks, guess I'll stick to this.

Answer (score 1):

Asking for easier way to do something dangerous…

Yes, there are a lot of ways to accomplish what you ask for, including

- C++ template,
- macro definition,
- editor shortcut,
- custom preprocessing,
- trained monkey that fixes up the code.

But all you accomplish is to make your code even less grokable.

Instead, try to figure out how come you so often *lose type information* so that you have to put it back by hand, so to speak.

The general solution is, very simply, to *not* throw away type information in the first place.

Comment: I cannot see how the last 3 solutions make the code less grokable. Also: can I have the monkey? (and does she fix bugs too?)

Comment: _how come you so often lose type information so that you have to put it back by hand_ For example using a scoped enum with a for loop or a hash function you need to cast everything back and forth.

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this?

```
#define SCAST(T,X) static_cast<T>(X);
```

I should warn you though that generally the overuse of defines like this can make your code obscure and harder to comprehend.

More importantly you have to watch out with macros as they can cause hard to find bugs for example:

```
#define SQUARE(X) = X*X;
```

Well if you call this with `x++`, the pre-processor will do a literal substitution and you'll end up with `(x++)*(x++);` which means it totally won't be the answer you're looking for and to make things worst because the substitution happens behind the scenes you'll have a hard time finding the cause.

I would suggest you instead look into template functions or just inline helper functions when you can, it's safe and will avoid the problem I pointed out.